# How can i change the visibility of my Variable x right?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, jbutton

This is my first program and now I am at a point i need help for a little problem.

```
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){ 
    String name[] = new String[5];
        name[0] = "Nefarax";
        name[1] = "Gohanner";
        name[2] = "Tiradus";
        name[3] = "Musti";
        name[4] = "Tarik";
        int x;

    // Die Quelle wird mit getSource() abgefragt und mit den
    // Buttons abgeglichen. Wenn die Quelle des ActionEvents einer
    // der Buttons ist, wird der Text des JLabels entsprechend geändert
    if(ae.getSource() == this.button1){
        label.setText(("Anzahl der WP für Nefarax eintragen: "));
        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(buttonOK);
        panel.add(tfName);
        buttonOK.setEnabled(true);
        tfName.setEnabled(true);
        x= 0;
    }
    else if(ae.getSource() == this.button2){
        label.setText("Button 2 wurde betätigt");
        buttonOK.setEnabled(true);
        tfName.setEnabled(true);
        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(buttonOK);
        panel.add(tfName);
        x=1;
    }
    else if (ae.getSource() == this.button3){
        label.setText(("Button 3 wurde betätigt"));
        buttonOK.setEnabled(true);
        tfName.setEnabled(true);
        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(buttonOK);
        panel.add(tfName);
        x=2;
    }

    else if (ae.getSource() == this.button4){
        label.setText(("Button 4 wurde betätigt"));
        buttonOK.setEnabled(true);
        tfName.setEnabled(true);
        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(buttonOK);
        panel.add(tfName);
        x=3;
    }

    else if (ae.getSource() == this.button5){
        label.setText("Button 5 wurde betätigt");
        buttonOK.setEnabled(true);
        tfName.setEnabled(true);
        buttonOK.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(buttonOK);
        panel.add(tfName);
        x=4;
    }

     if(ae.getSource() == this.buttonOK){

        label.setText(" ");
        buttonOK.setEnabled(false);
        tfName.setEnabled(false);

        save(name[x]);
     }   
    }
 public void save(String name)
{
    try
    {


        File file = new File("C:\\daten\\Wichtig\\" + name  +"Points.txt");
        if(!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        writer.write(tfName.getText()+ ";");

        writer.close();

    }

    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es ist ein Fehler beim Speichern aufgetreten." );
    }

}
```

}

`save(name[x])` is not initiated but i don't know how?
I need this array to create `.txt` files with different names and for every button theres a new name

thanks

Comment: `x` has no default value, and is not assigned a value if none of the `if()` statements is executed. Hence `x` not being initialized.

Comment: what is your x's value if none of the if's executed?

Comment: Also, since `ActionEvent.getSource()` returns an object, it might be advisable to use `.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: @JaimieWhiteside not mandatory, since `getSource()` returns the object on which the action occurred. So the references are the same since the object is not copied.

Comment: It still is a good practice though...

Comment: thanks now i have changed int x; to int x = 0; but when i press button 5 x is still 0 and the name doesnt change

Comment: Kind of Off Topic, but i am pretty sure that `abspeichern` is not a good name for a function. While i do know what it means, the mayority of users here will not get it. Please consider writing your code in english. Nobody want's to read statements like `connect_to(DatenbankSchnittstelle).query(Abfragezeichenkette)` ;-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to initialize it, in the declaration, just set it to a certain value..
for example `-1`:

```
int x = -1;
```

or, optionally you can also use `Integer` instead of `int`

```
Integer x = null;
```

just remember before calling function `abspeichern()`, you also need to handle this further..
(this `-1` or `null` value); unless it might cause an error

like:

```
if(ae.getSource() == this.buttonOK){

    label.setText(" ");
    buttonOK.setEnabled(false);
    tfName.setEnabled(false);

    if(x!=null){
        abspeichern(name[x]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `abspeichern()` function has a String parameter.. ;) So OP will get a `NullPointerException` on `abspeicheren(name[null]);`

Comment: that's why: before calling.. :)